# How configure a gradle multi-module project?

Tags: kotlin, gradle, multi-module

I have a 3 microservices and now i need to create a docker-compose for all of it. So when i trying to fellow all my microservices in one project i get this issue

```
Project directory 'C:\Users\Dany\IdeaProjects\target-root\target-discovery\app' is not part of the build defined by settings file 'C:\Users\Dany\IdeaProjects\target-root\settings.gradle.kts'. If this is an unrelated build, it must have its own settings file.
```

What i have to read for fix it?

**setting.gradle.kts**

[image]

**project structure**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The include in `settings.gradle.kts` should look like:

```kotlin
include(
  ":target-discovery"
)
```

in case there are more sub-folders (e.g. target-discovery/app, target-discovery/app2):

```kotlin
include(
  ":target-discovery:app",
  ":target-discovery:app2"
)
```

When defining a module it should always start with `:` and sub-folders should be delimited by `:`

Also make sure your root `build.gradle.kts` define all relevant plugins or define them in each sub-module. You can also create conventions (https://docs.gradle.org/current/samples/sample_convention_plugins.html)

If you just define `plugins` in the root it wont affect your sub-projects, one way to achive it (altough i prefer convention plugins) is:

*build.gradle.kts*

```kotlin
plugins {
  kotlin("jvm") version ...
}

subprojects {
  apply(plugin = "kotlin")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Tom said, what you need to include isn't `target-discovery` but `target-discovery/app`
However, projects included in `settings.gradle` (or `settings.gradle.kts`) don't start with the colon symbol, so you should have:

*settings.gradle.kts*

```
rootProject.name = "target-root"
include("target-discovery:app")
```